# Attach an failover IP to a machine

Tags: email, dns, window, windows-server-2016

**To resume the situation :** I'm trying to use a new set of failover ip on my email serveur, after seting up the DNS, but the software I use on my email serveur (SmarterMail) doesn't see them. Why that ?

**This is the complete situation :**

- I have a domaine name "ept.com" having a "A DNS record" to the physical IP machine.
- mail1.ept.com has its A record to IP Failover IPA1
- mail2.ept.com has its A record to IP Failover IPA2
- mail3.ept.com has its A record to IP Failover IPA3

**My goal** : change IPA1, IPA2, IPA3 with IPB1, IPB2, IPB3

So I bought those new IP on OVH and set up the DNS :

- mail1.ept.com has its A record to IP Failover IPB1
- mail2.ept.com has its A record to IP Failover IPB2
- mail3.ept.com has its A record to IP Failover IPB3

Propagation is complete. Then I setup reverse DNS. All is good so far.

**The problem :** Smartermail (software installed on the server) is supposed to list all the ip attached to the physical machine but all I can see is the old IP, not the new ones. So I am unable to tell him to use the "mail1.ept.com" smtp serveur with IPB1, "mail2.ept.com" with IPB2 etc

**My question :** Why does smartermail not see the new failover IP ? Is it matter of time ? (I setup the DNS 5 hours ago) My serveur is a Window Server 2016 Standard, should I do something window-specific ?

I am a beginner with that stuf, so I hope I've explained well... Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

I needed to go in Ethernet connection's properties, click on "Internet Protocol V4" and then the Properties button.

[image: Internet Protocol V4]

In the window that pops up, I clicked on the "advanced" button.

[image: clicked on the advanced button]

In this last window I could add the new IPs in order to be pulled by Smartermail.

[image: Add the new ip]